# Different results with observed=True/False in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am getting different results when using groupby in pandas after using observed=True/False in a dataframe with a categorical column with intervals. In principle, I believe I should have exactly the same results.

As an example, let's assume the following dataframe:

```py
    df_testing = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["good", "good", "good", "bad", "good", "good", "bad", "good",
                                "good", "good"],
                          "b": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11111, -5455]})
```

I transform the "b" column so to group the values into different intervals. I also force the "a" column to be categorical:

```py
    df_testing["a"] = df_testing["a"].astype("category")
    df_testing["b"] = pd.cut(df_testing["b"], [-9999, 0, 2, 5, 1e99], right=True)
```

If I put the observed = False, the results are correct:

```py
    In[310]: df_testing.groupby(by="b", observed=False)["a"].value_counts()

    Out[310]:
    b               a   
    (-9999.0, 0.0]  good    1
    (0.0, 2.0]      good    3
                    bad     1
    (2.0, 5.0]      good    2
                    bad     1
    (5.0, 1e+99]    good    2
    Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But for observed = True:

```py
    In[311]: df_testing.groupby(by="b", observed=True)["a"].value_counts()

    Out[311]:
    b               a   
    (0.0, 2.0]      good    1
    (2.0, 5.0]      good    3
                    bad     1
    (5.0, 1e+99]    good    2
                    bad     1
    (-9999.0, 0.0]  good    2
    Name: a, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, the counting is the same... But the labels for the b column in the second case are wrong!

I am using pandas v0.24.2 (latest stable version)

Comment: I think it is bug, the best report it in [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas)

Comment: Haha! Yes bug..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25871) that has been fixed for the upcoming 0.25.0 release:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.25.0.dev0+596.g20d0ad159a'

In [2]: df_testing = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["good", "good", "good", "bad", "good", "good",
   ...:                                  "bad", "good", "good", "good"],
   ...:                            "b": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11111, -5455]})

In [3]: df_testing["a"] = df_testing["a"].astype("category")

In [4]: df_testing["b"] = pd.cut(df_testing["b"], [-9999, 0, 2, 5, 1e99], right=True)

In [5]: df_testing.groupby(by="b", observed=False)["a"].value_counts()
Out[5]:
b               a
(-9999.0, 0.0]  good    1
(0.0, 2.0]      good    3
                bad     1
(2.0, 5.0]      good    2
                bad     1
(5.0, 1e+99]    good    2
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [6]: df_testing.groupby(by="b", observed=True)["a"].value_counts()
Out[6]:
b               a
(-9999.0, 0.0]  good    1
(0.0, 2.0]      good    3
                bad     1
(2.0, 5.0]      good    2
                bad     1
(5.0, 1e+99]    good    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Add for those of us still on versions before 0.25.0 - how to fix this / what is a workaround? Thank you